# AsNoTracking and Remove

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to delete a row from the Database usin this code

```
public ListPicture GetPicture(string Id)
{
  ListPicture pic = Pictures.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(x => x.pId == Id);
  return pic;
}

public void DeletePicture(string Id)
{
  ListPicture pic = GetPicture(Id);
  if( pic != null)
  {
     Pictures.Remove(pic);
  }
  SaveChanges();
}
```

On remove I have this error

> System.InvalidOperationException: The object cannot be deleted because it was not found in the ObjectStateManager.

I tried to attached the entity pic to Pictures

```
public void DeletePicture(string Id)
{
  ListPicture pic = GetPicture(Id);
  if( pic != null)
  {
      Pictures.Attach(pic);
      Pictures.Remove(pic);
   }
   SaveChanges();
 }
```

this is the error is :

> System.InvalidOperationException: Attaching an entity of type 'Album.DatabaseContext.ListPicture' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value.

the function GetPicture is used many times in my application, how can I resolve this issue

Comment: where and how did you try to attach pic to your EF context?

Comment: I added the attach code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, apparently the entity has to be tracked (loaded) in the context.

So either don't use the `GetPicture` method (I know, code duplication but...):

```
ListPicture pic = Pictures.FirstOrDefault(x => x.pId == Id);
if (pic != null)
{
    Pictures.Remove(pic);
}
SaveChanges();
```

or if the `Pictures` is `DbSet<T>` (as it seems from the posted code), you can use the [`Find`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696418(v=vs.113).aspx) method instead:

```
ListPicture pic = Pictures.Find(Id);
if (pic != null)
{
    Pictures.Remove(pic);
}
SaveChanges();
```

Both approaches will ensure the returned instance is attached to the context.

Comment: This what I thought, I didn't want to duplicate code -- thank you

Answer (score 6):

When you use `AsNoTracking`, EF does not maintain data for entities that have been loaded into the proxy. That is, it is an entity that no longer relies on EF for anything.

However, this entity exists in the database.
When attempting to execute an Attach, the EF checks that there already exists someone with the same Id and throws the exception.

My suggestion is:

1: Remove the `AsNoTracking` from GetPicture method.
2: If you cannot, make your Delete method like this:

```
public ListPicture GetPicture(string Id)
{
    ListPicture pic = Pictures.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(x => x.pId == Id);
    return pic;
}

public void DeletePicture(string Id)
{
    ListPicture pic = Pictures.Find(id);
    if( pic != null)
    {
       Pictures.Remove(pic);
    }
    SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are not sure if it will be attached or not (*and based on the Exceptions you are getting it could be either or*) then you can add a check on the `DbContext` instance to see if it is attached and attach it if it is not. This requires access to the `DbContext` instance that is being used.

Alternatively make sure that you always return an attached entity and do not use `AsNoTracking()`.

```
public void DeletePicture(string Id)
{
  ListPicture pic = GetPicture(Id);
  if( pic != null)
  {
      // add check if instance is attached
      if(contextInstance.Entry(pic).State == System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Detached)
        Pictures.Attach(pic);
      Pictures.Remove(pic);
   }
   SaveChanges(); // this could be moved to inside the if block
}
```